# Mark not used modules in Python in VS Code as like in PyCharm

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Pycharm is identifying not used modules in the Python script, so you can have an overview about the modules. In my Template the unused modules are grey, the used modules are blue. I googled it, but I didn't found an extension to resolve this in VS Code.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature request that should be filed at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python. Otherwise you should run a linter that will provide you with such a warning such as [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/2.5.5/warnings.html).